# Accessing object properties with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I know there are several ways to create Objects, add Methods and Properties etc.
There is one thing I don't understand about prototypes

```
  function Obj () {
    var msg = "message";

    this.log = function (){
      console.log(msg);
    }
  }
  var o = new Obj();
  o.log();
```

this would output message. however using a prototype

```
function Obj2 () {
  var msg = "message2";

}

Obj2.prototype.log = function () {
  console.log(msg);
}

var o2 = new Obj2();
o2.log();
```

would output that msg is not defined.
why is that?

Comment: You can learn about variable scope here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope

Answer (score 1):

`msg` is a variable that is scoped to `Obj` and `Obj2` respectively.

The `log` function in the first example is defined within the scope of `Obj` so it has access to variables from that scope.

The `log` function in the second example is not defined within that scope of `Obj2`, so it doesn't.

Comment: is there any way around it? or is it not possible to access private properties from prototypes?

Comment: @user3144851: There are no "private properties". You are simulating this by using local variables, and variables are subject to lexical scope.

Comment: It isn't possible to access private variables from prototypes. Make the variable a property on the object instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope problem as mentioned by @Quentin, However if you need to access the variable inside the prototype function, you need to make use of this and treat it as a class. So now it will be treated as a property to the class Obj2 and not as a private variable.

So the code will be like:

```
function Obj2 () {
  this.msg = "message2";

}

Obj2.prototype.log = function () {
  console.log(this.msg);
}

var o2 = new Obj2();
o2.log();
```

[Fiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/g995o9kk/)